# BCP import with accented characters for SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, command-line, sql-server-2012, bcp

I have created a .csv file for bcp in this format :

```
x,y,z(CR LF)
x,y,z(CR LF) etc...
```

I have the bcp in command working as below:

```
bcp "{table}" in "{csv path}" -S {server} -t -T -q -w -f "{format xml file}"
```

Using the below format command & file:

```
bcp "{table}" format nul -t, -T -q -S {server} -f {format file} -x
```

This works and uploads, but does not upload accented characters correctly.

I've looked through [SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-unicode-character-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#special_considerations) but the examples are not solving this issue.

My .csv is in this data format:

```
bigint, date, date, nvarchar, varchar, varchar, bigint, bigint
```

Am I misunderstanding, should I be correcting the format file, the upload IN command, or perhaps both?

Thank you.

*Edit:*
Based on [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/non-xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
I have now begun manually creating a format file as below - which always leads to Invalid field size for datatype error.

```
11.0
8
1       SQLCHAR         0       15      ","      1     fn1 Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLDATE         1       3       ","      2     fn2 ""
3       SQLDATE         1       3       ","      3     fn3 ""
4       SQLNCHAR        2       510     ","      4     fn4 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR         2       50      ","      5     fn5 Latin1_General_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR         2       40      ","      6     fn6 Latin1_General_CI_AS
7       SQLBIGINT       1       8       ","      7     fn7 ""
8       SQLBIGINT       1       8       "\r\n"   8     fn8 ""
```

I also have changed the collation on the table nchar field to 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

Comment: You'll need the `-C` option to tell `bcp` what encoding your file is in. The "default code page" it uses is not necessarily what you want. `-C ACP` uses Windows-1252 and is appropriate for a great many cases; `-C 65001` uses UTF-8 in recent versions (2016+) and is the most "universal" approach, as long as you can save your CSV in UTF-8 as well, of course.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Would a UTF-8 CSV need a BOM or need to *not* have a BOM or it doesn't care?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: That's an excellent question -- to which I don't know the answer, since the `bcp` docs are silent on the matter and I can't recall what happened the last time I tried this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks. I appended -C ACP to the IN command, however, no dice. Is the format file taking priority over the -C command? 
As an aside, I changed 'Latin1_General_CI_AS' to 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' in the XML, but no change.

Comment: @jmejay Could you try it with the data encoded as `UTF-16LE` with no BOM? (From Erland Sommarskog's replies in [bcp unicode](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/bcp-unicode).)

Comment: I don't believe the format file has any impact on this. The collation of the database columns is different from the input file encoding -- the file has only one encoding, so it would not do to switch it for individual columns. That said, `bcp` has weirder warts, so yeah. Make sure you actually *know* what the encoding of your input file is, first -- "accented characters go wrong" in itself can't tell you that. In Notepad, you can use the "Encoding" drop-down in "File -> Save As" to specify this.

Comment: Will do. It's currently UTF-8 - I am looking into @AndrewMorton 's suggestion now.

Comment: @jmejay Some people had success with bcp in [Insert rows with Unicode characters using BCP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41507292/1115360).

Comment: with/without BOM makes no difference. The collation of the format file has precedence over the encoding flag of the command line: If you try to import data into SQL Server using bcp in -c -C65001 -f format_file ..." or "BULK INSERT/OPENROWSET ... FORMATFILE='format_file' CODEPAGE=65001 ...", information about the collation/code page will have priority over 65001 option.

Comment: I should say, I am using SQL Server 2012 unfortunately. UCS-2-LE BOM gives "Invalid character value for cast specification" error.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - do you think my answer might be in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-native-and-character-format-data-from-earlier-versions-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) Still no luck so far. Any modifications I try above give the invalid field size for datatype error. Thanks

Comment: @jmejay I don't think so. Can you export some data which has NVARCHAR columns  with accented characters with BCP and see what it saves it as natively?

Comment: @jmejay I just found this from MS: [Special Considerations for Using Unicode Character Format, bcp, and a Format File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-unicode-character-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#special-considerations-for-using-unicode-character-format-bcp-and-a-format-file).

Comment: @lptr - I've added my format file to the main question - can you see anything glaringly wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewMorton good idea with the export - I used -c and -C RAW ; which let me save the correct accented chars to the .bcp output file. I haven't cracked the upload issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it at last!

I changed my bcp input .csv into ANSI format, and created my .fmt file with code page 1252.

I also ensured my SQL table field was collated to *SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS*

So, once the .csv was ANSI my format code was:

```
bcp "table" format nul -q -T -S {server} -t, -r \n -f C:\LocalStuff\abc.fmt -c -C 1252 -x
```

Once uploading with abc.fmt, it works!

Thanks everyone who helped.

Comment: It's great this worked for you, though it's worth noting that, necessarily, this makes it impossible to import characters not in Windows-1252 (which couldn't be stored in a `VARCHAR` with that collation, but could be stored in an `NVARCHAR`, which you also have).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, thank you. Luckily my import file is common accent characters. I tried a few code pages but I think this is an unfortunate limitation of being stuck in SQL 2012!

Comment: This should be a limitation of `bcp` only, though, not the SQL Server engine itself (save the lack of UTF-8 support in the columns itself, but that's obvious and not necessary to solve this problem) -- newer versions of `bcp` (available as [separate downloads on the doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/bcp-utility)) can at least be installed on other machines (I don't know if they will play nice with existing installations of SQL Server when installed locally, so best not try that). Of course your problem is now already solved, but still.